# Indefinite integral - interval of validity of this equality $\int \frac{1}{\sin(x) \cdot \cos(x)} \, dx = \ln \left|\tan(x)\right|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, indefinite-integrals

This is an easy integral so I am just looking for a simple confirmation.

The integral and the answer which I see in my book is this one.

$$\int \frac{1}{\sin(x) \cdot \cos(x)} \, dx = \ln \left|\tan(x)\right|$$

But they say this is true/valid only for $$x \in (0, \pi/2)$$

while I think it is true for $x \in (-\pi/2, 0) \cup (0, \pi/2)$

Am I correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right. The sign of $x$ can either be positive or negative without changing the result. If $x < 0$, we let $t = - x$, $dt = - dx$, then:
$$\int \frac{1}{\sin x \cdot \cos x}\,\mathrm{d}x = \int \frac{-1}{\sin (-t)\cdot \cos (-t)}\,\mathrm{d}t=\int \frac{1}{\sin t \cdot \cos t} \, \mathrm{d}t=$$

$$ = \ln \left\vert\tan t \right\vert +C =\ln \left\vert \tan x \right\vert+C$$
where $C$ is a constant.

Comment: In particular, the most general antiderivative takes $C$ to be a *locally constant function* that can change at each multiple of $\pi/2$.

Comment: So the answer is not completely correct, confirming the OP hypothesis $x\in(-\pi/2,0)\cup(0,\pi/2)$, while the primitive is defined in each interval $(k \pi/2,(k+1)\pi/2)$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: I am interested in the interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ Of course I can generalize this to other intervals. I wanted to confirm that the equality is true for all $x \ne 0$ in this interval basically. And not just for those $x$ which are in $(0, \pi/2)$

Comment: You say $C$ is constant, and that's right if it's understood to mean "piecewise contant." It can change when you go from one connected component of the domain to another.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer of Quan: usually, the integral notation without any set or bounds specified is the notation for indefinite integral, which corresponds to any possible antiderivative (or in a more formal way, the set of antiderivatives). Since the function is not integrable at $x=0$, the antiderivative is not defined in $0$, and so has to be defined on $(-\pi/2,0)\cup (0,\pi/2)$ (if we are only interested in the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$)

On this domain, the antiderivatives take the form:
$$
\begin{align*}
F(x) &= \ln|\tan(x)| + C_1 \text{ if } x>0
\\
&= \ln|\tan(x)| + C_2 \text{ if } x<0
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: You wrote $(-\pi,\pi)$?

Comment: Yeah, I know what indefinite integral is. Thanks for the reply.